# from json object to my object properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, pickadate

This is a little hard to explain. I got this from server:

```
{"enable": "15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23",
"disable": "{ from: new Date(2014,9,16,23,0), to: new Date(2014,9,16,23,0) }"}
```

and this is how I try to set the enabled and disables hours to my pickatime object from that JSON object. (http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api.htm#method-set-disable-enable)

```
        $.get('/ajax/res/', function(data) {
            var picker = $("#rz-time-1").pickatime('picker');

            picker.set('enable', [
                data.enable
            ]);
            picker.set('disable', [
                data.disable
            ]);
        }, 'json');
```

this doesn't work, however if I put $.parseJSON(data.enable) it works only if there is not commas in my string... otherwise I get **unexpected non-whitespace character** because of the commas...

Comment: Well, `{ from: new Date(2014,9,16,23,0), to: new Date(2014,9,16,23,0) }` is clearly not valid JSON. You can verify that using http://jsonlint.org/. So `$.parseJSON(data.enable)` can't possibly work. You should fix the code that generates the response.

Comment: the link that you provide please that clear-fully they want date format in there particular format
picker.set('enable', [
    [2014,9,9],
    [2014,9,13],
    new Date(2013,9,20)
])

Comment: @FelixKling actually it is valid, but have to eval part of it

Comment: @charlietfl: No, it's not valid. I may be valid JS which can be `eval`ed, but it's not valid JSON.

Comment: @FelixKling passes through jsonlint.com fine. Look close where the quotes are

Comment: @charlietfl: I believe you are talking about the whole response. Yes, that's valid JSON. However, my comment was explicitly referring to `"{ from: new Date(2014,9,16,23,0), to: new Date(2014,9,16,23,0) }"`, which is the value of `data.disabled`. And actually rereading the question I noticed that the OP tried to use `$.parseJSON` on `data.enabled`, which is not valid JSON either.

Comment: While my first comment applies to the value of `data.enabled` as well. `15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23` is not valid JSON. I recommend to read about JSON: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON.

Comment: ahhh but the whole thing is valid...just a very very strange and unfriendly way to deliver data. `enable` value would have to be split to use as array, but it's still a valid JSON string

Comment: @FelixKling $.parseJSON was just a try to see if that method works, and it works if my there is not commas, so I think it needs to be parsed or something like that... actually if I call picker.set('enable', [1,2,3,4]) it works as documentation says... but it doesn't if that string "1,2,3,4" comes as a value from a json object.

Comment: Why did you expect it to work? `"1,2,3,4"` is a **string** and `[1,2,3,4]` is an **array**. Those are two different values of different data types! Change the code that generates the response to return `{"enabled": [1,2,3,4]}` instead (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example). *"it works if my there is not commas"* Yes, because `1` is valid JSON. `1, 2` is not valid JSON.

Comment: That's a invalid json .only arrays and primitive values are supported in JSON.you cannot have object creation statements in JSON

Comment: @FelixKling oops... omg what a fool, thanks!! {"enabled": [1,2,3,4]} is how it should be...

Answer (score 0):

The `new Date(2014,9,16,23,0)` in your JSON is invalid. Also, why is the disable value a string? It looks like it should not.

Instead of using `new Date(...)`, you could possibly use an array:

```
{
  "enable": "15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23",
  "disable": {
    "from": [2014,9,16,23,0],
    "to": [2014,9,16,23,0]
  }
}
```

Now you can access the specific parts of what was the illegal `new Date`.